# Jframe de java no detecta objeto al pulsar botón

Tags: java, jframe, data-atributos

Quiero pasar un objeto `Jugador` de un ***jframe*** a otro, y que luego pueda operar con él al pulsar un botón.

Tengo puesto que, al pulsar un botón e instanciar la otra ventana, se pase el objeto con el constructor, como podréis ver en jButton3MouseClicked:

```
public Inicio() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("jugadoresinterf.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        jugadores = (HashMap) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        System.out.println("Elemento no encontrado.");
        c.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Correcto");
}


private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Registro_jug reg = new Registro_jug();
    reg.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}                                     

private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String user = jTextField1.getText();
    String pass = jPasswordField1.getText();
    if (jugadores.containsKey(user)) {
        Jugador j1 = jugadores.get(user);
        if (j1.getPassword().equals(pass)) {
            Juego juego = new Juego(j1);
            juego.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.", "Error de login", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Después de esto, la ventana `Juego` lo recibe:

```
public Juego(Jugador j1) {
    initComponents();
    jTextField2.setText(j1.getNombre());
    jTextField3.setText(Double.toString(j1.getSaldo()));
    Apuesta apuesta = new Apuesta();
}
```

Sin embargo, si quiero llamarlo desde un jButton1MouseClicked no me lo detecta:

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println(j1.getSaldo());
```

[image: Error]

El main de juego es este, por si sirve de algo:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juego.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juego.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juego.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juego.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Jugador j1 = new Jug_Reg("ABCDE-FGHIJ-KMNLO", "99999999N", "TESTBOT", 2000.00, 6, 6, 1950, "12345678");
            new Juego(j1).setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Le puse un jugador testbot para que no pete si ejecuto la ventana sin pasar por Inicio.

¿Cómo le paso al botón `actionperformed` el jugador recibido del constructor?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No detectará la variable dado que la variable que recibes en el constructor **`estará disponible solo para el constructor`** , si deseas acceder desde otro lado como posible solución puedes asignarlo antes a un variable a nivel de `Clase`.

```
private Jugador jugadorRecibido;  /* Declaramos la variable a Nivel Clase*/
public Juego(Jugador j1) {
   initComponents();
   jTextField2.setText(j1.getNombre());
   jTextField3.setText(Double.toString(j1.getSaldo()));
   jugadorRecibido = j1; /* Asignamos j1 a la variable de nivel Clase*/
   Apuesta apuesta = new Apuesta();
}
```

Y ya para llamarlo desde cualquier método o evento , solo debes acceder a la variable `jugadorRecibido`

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
   System.out.println(jugadorRecibido.getSaldo());  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes toda la razón del mundo. Es como siempre se ha hecho, solo que con todo el lío de la interfaz me acabo olvidando. Muchas gracias por todo.